# How can I make this jQuery function more efficient with looping?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to use jQuery to find elements, get their nested paragraph and then add in a div before this paragraph. I have it working fine, but it's very repetitive code and I want to make it more efficient and tidy it up, but I'm not sure how.

Here is the code:

```
$(".container .row").each(function(index) {
    var row1,
        row2,
        row3,
        row4,
        newRow1,
        newRow2,
        newRow3,
        newRow4;

    row1 = jQuery(this).find(".elementA");
    row2 = jQuery(this).find(".elementB");
    row3 = jQuery(this).find(".elementC");
    row4 = jQuery(this).find(".elementD");

    newRow1 = row1.find("p");
    newRow2 = row2.find("p");
    newRow3 = row3.find("p");
    newRow4 = row4.find("p");

    $("<div>Test 1</div>").insertBefore(newRow1);
    $("<div>Test 1</div>").insertBefore(newRow2);
    $("<div>Test 1</div>").insertBefore(newRow3);
    $("<div>Test 1</div>").insertBefore(newRow4);

    return;
});
```

Comment: Make all your `element(X)` class as `element` and just have remove repetitive lines of codes

Comment: Can you add HTML sample?

Comment: @AkshayKhandelwal this is a sample, in reality each element(x) is a different class name.

Comment: If it's working code, you may wish to ask over at [codereview.se]...

Answer (score 3):

1. Take the `div` html string outside of the loop
2. You can remove all the variables
3. Cache `this` context
4. `return` at the end is not necessary

Code:

```
var div = "<div>Test 1</div>";
$(".container .row").each(function (index) {
    var $this = jQuery(this);

    $(div).insertBefore($this.find(".elementA p"));
    $(div).insertBefore($this.find(".elementB p"));
    $(div).insertBefore($this.find(".elementC p"));
    $(div).insertBefore($this.find(".elementD p"));
});
```

You can also shorten your code as follow if you want to iterate over all the elements whose class starts with `element`:

```
var div = "<div>Test 1</div>";
$(".container .row [class^=element] p").each(function () {
    $(div).insertBefore($(this));
});
```

I'll also suggest you to use the same class name to all the elements instead of `elementX`.

Comment: `[class^=element] ` would also select `.elementE` , if was in document

Comment: @guest271314 You're right. Kindly check the update - `if you want to iterate over all the elements whose class starts with element`. This completely depends on the DOM structure. Also, I believe OP wants to iterate over all the elements. Why would you leave an element from a common elements?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like normal selectors can reduce the load.

```
$(".container .row").each(function (index) {
    var newRow = jQuery(this).find(".elementA p, .elementB p, .elementC p, .elementD p");
    $("<div>Test 1</div>").insertBefore(newRow);
    return;
});
```

Comment: can that elementA or whatever class be made jsut **element**

Comment: An i think you'd need a each loop for newRow

Comment: @AkshayKhandelwal I don't think that will be necessary.